# I have been struggling with find out how to call a function can someone explain what I am doing wrong in this example

Tags: python, debugging

```
#create function with two paramaters
def quiz_item(question,solution):
  
#ask question and get input
 
  question = input("The blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived. ")
  solution = "T"
#while loop
  while question != solution:
    question = input("INCORECT try again: The blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived. ")
    #if answer is == to solution print correct
    if question == solution:
      print("That is correct!")
      break
quiz_item(question,solution)
```

#output says solution not defined

## How should I call the function for the code to run

Comment: You're passing in a `question` but ignoring it. Your logic largely looks fine, but it depends on what you want to happen.

Comment: You don't seem to quite understand what function parameters are for.  Both of the parameters in this case are pointless (you immediately overwrite them with other values), and the call is invalid because you're trying to pass variables that aren't defined in that scope.

Comment: You are calling the function in your last line, however, you have not defined any value for `question` or `solution` parameters that you are passing to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're still learning. That's nice!

Very well. You'll have multiple solutions but i'll try to explain the simplest of them.

Simplest solution: You can define the function without any arguments. Like this:

```
#create function with two paramaters
def quiz_item():
  
  #ask question and get input     
  question = input("The blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived. ")
  solution = "T"

  #while loop
  while question != solution:
    question = input("INCORECT try again: The blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived. ")
    #if answer is == to solution print correct
    if question == solution:
      print("That is correct!")
      break

quiz_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

You already define the variables 'question' and 'solution' **inside** the function, so no need to pass them as parameters when calling to the function.

Your code should look like this:

```
#create function with two paramaters
def quiz_item():
    # ask question and get input
    question = input("The blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived. ")
    solution = "T"
    # while loop
    while question != solution:
        question = input("INCORECT try again: The blue whale is the biggest animal to have ever lived. ")
        #if answer is == to solution print correct
        if question == solution:
            print("That is correct!")
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    quiz_item()
```